# Auto-suggestion ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox and the JComboBox has so many items. I want to add “auto-suggestion” feature on the JComboBox.

Like this: I have 3 items, “Artpop”, “Born This Way”, and “Chromatica”. If I type “Way” then the autocomplete selects the “Born This Way" item. If I type "matica" then the autocomplete selects the "Chromatica" item.

I was looking for it on StackOverflow, but all the answers are outdated (I'm using Swing, while the answers are for AWT. When I do the answers, I've got several errors).

How to make auto-suggestion Swing JComboBox?

Comment: When a combo box is in focus and the user types the first letters of an item it contains, that item will become selected. How much more 'auto' do you want?

Comment: [@AndrewThompson] Like this: I have 3 items, “Artpop”, “Born This Way”, and “Chromatica”. If I type “Way” then the autocomplete selects the “Born This Way" item. If i type "matica" then the autocomplete selects the "Chromatica" item.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever seen that implemented as a single control.  What I have seen is a combobox (or list or table) with a text field beside it for filtering.

Comment: [@VGR] Please tell me how to make it on Swing.

Comment: What happens if you just type `a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a `JTextField` and a `JComboBox` to create an auto-suggestion combo box.

Here's an example I put together.  Unfortunately, the GUI picture doesn't display the JComboBox correctly.

[image: Auto Suggestion Example GUI]

I created a simple GUI with a `JTextField` and a `JComboBox`.

When you type a character in the `JTextField`, the `JComboBox` options are reduced to the `Strings` that contain that character.  The search is not case sensitive.  If you type a *w*, it will return all `Strings` with a *w* or a *W*.

Here's the complete, runnable code I used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AutoSuggestionExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AutoSuggestionExample());
    }
    
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboBoxModel;
    
    private JTextField autoSuggestionField;
    
    private List<String> masterList;
    
    public AutoSuggestionExample() {
        String[] masterList = { "Artpop", "Born This Way", "Chromatica" };
        this.masterList = Arrays.asList(masterList);
        this.comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(masterList);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Auto Suggestion Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        autoSuggestionField = new JTextField(20);
        autoSuggestionField.addKeyListener(new AutoSuggestionListener());
        panel.add(autoSuggestionField);
        
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(comboBoxModel);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        panel.add(comboBox);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public List<String> createSelectedList(String search) {
        if (search.isEmpty()) {
            return masterList;
        }
        
        search = search.toLowerCase();
        List<String> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : masterList) {
            if (s.toLowerCase().contains(search)) {
                selectedList.add(s);
            }
        }
        
        return selectedList;
    }
    
    public void updateComboBox(List<String> selectedList) {
        comboBoxModel.removeAllElements();
        comboBoxModel.addAll(selectedList);
        if (selectedList.size() > 0) {
            comboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(selectedList.get(0));
        }
    }
    
    public class AutoSuggestionListener extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            String text = autoSuggestionField.getText() + event.getKeyChar();
            updateComboBox(createSelectedList(text));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Does `mboBoxModel.addAll(selectedList);`  compile ?  I think `DefaultComboBoxModel` does not support it.

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't compile for me. I think using the information entered by the user to select without modifying the combobox could be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Thompson commented: "When a combo box is in focus and the user types the first letters of an item it contains, that item will become selected" 
This behavior is defined in the public method [JComboBox.selectWithKeyChar(char keyChar)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#selectWithKeyChar(char)).
You can extend `JComboBox` to override `selectWithKeyChar(char keyChar)` to define a different behavior.

Comment: The problem with modifying the JComboBox edit field is that the user can type anything and fail to actually make a selection.  To put it another way, the selection may not exist.  By using a separate JTextField, the JComboBox always points to a valid selection, assuming your code sets a default selection.

Comment: It is certainly an issue. If there is no selection you can always let `super.selectWithKeyChar(char keyChar)` do the selection.